# Generic nested monad manipulation?

Tags: haskell, monads

I've been [given](http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/20-intermediate-haskell-exercises/) the following class interface:

```
class Misty m where
  banana :: (a -> m b) -> m a -> m b
  unicorn :: a -> m a
```

And now I'm required to modify this to enable:

```
jellybean :: (Misty m) => m (m a) -> m a
```

I believe the question is pushing me to add a subclass of `Misty`, with multi parameters:

```
class Misty m => VeryMisty m a where
  ... banana' (Just (Just v)) = banana --?
```

I'm unsure how to create a function in `Misty` to operate on this nested monad?

I'm also unsure whether my approach is correct and/or the simplest?

Comment: I think you just have to define `jellybean` in terms of `banana` and `unicorn`

Comment: You do realize that `Misty` is `Monad`, `banana` is `=<<` (flipped `>>=`), `unicorn` is `return`, and `jellybean` is `join`, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you don't have to extend the class, or add a subclass. Consider what the type signature of `banana` looks like if you would pick `m a` for the `a` in the signature of `banana` (the type variable `a` can stand for any type, so also for `m a`):

```
banana :: Misty m => (m a -> m b) -> m (m a) -> m b
```

Do you see that this already starts to look quite close to `jellybean`? You only have to "get rid" of the first argument, and make `b` to be the same as `a`. The easiest way to achieve this would be to use the identity function `id`:

```
jellybean :: (Misty m) => m (m a) -> m a
jellybean x = banana id x
```

A nice way to see the second step easier is that once you discover that you could use the first argument to `jellybean` as the second of `banana` is to use a *typed hole*:

```
jellybean :: (Misty m) => m (m a) -> m a
jellybean x = banana _ x
```

On loading this into the REPL, Haskell will print out:

```
 Found hole `_' with type: m a -> m a
```

So you see what you'll need here to make this typecheck in this context.